# Ignore Twig's variable and transform it to Polymer's variable.

Tags: escaping

I've encountered on a problem with escaping, where I want some parts of code, not being translated by Twig.

Straight to the problem.

[Polymer](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query), uses the same marking for variables as Twig, and I'm not sure, if it's possible to escape variable as a Twig's variable and transform it to a Polymer's variable

By Twig's documentation, I've end up with this:

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="'{{'{{queryMatches}}'}}'">
```

where it translates to:

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="'{{queryMatches}}'"></iron-media-query>
```

The goal is:

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{queryMatches}}"></iron-media-query>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to remove the outer single quotes in your first example

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{'{{queryMatches}}'}}">
```

Try the `raw` filter if that doesnt work. More info on it [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)